# Placing a jumbotron over a carousel in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm attempting to simply place a jumbotron on top of a carousel in Bootstrap 5.

I figured out a work around, but for some reason my Jumbotron does not overlay the carousel.

The goal here is to have a static message with two active buttons lay on top as the carousel goes through the slides behind it.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!-- Jumbo Tron -->
      <div class="jumbotron bg-light">
        <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
        <p class="lead">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">KVLF The Voice of the Big Bend</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">KALP Big Bend Country</a>
        </p>
      </div>


      <!-- Carousel -->
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="img/Wstorefront.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/Wsocks1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/Wstoreinterior1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>




</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to add carousel slider and on carousel top set some content like buttons, text etc.

Here is an example of the carousel slider with custom content

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Custom content on top -->
    <div style="
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    right: auto;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
"><button>Show More</button><p style="
    color: white;
">Static contant</p></div>
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
         
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate that a lot, I'm just trying to add a button and text ontop of a sliding carousel that doens't move away as the pictures change.  Ideally, I'd like the Text and Buttons to stay static, while there is a slideshow moving behind said text.  Thank you much for your feedback and it will be very useful as I continue my learning through the Bootstraping world.